# Build CFG for $L=\{a^ib^kc^i| \,(i+k)\equiv1 \pmod 3\}$

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

So I need to find CFG for $$L=\{a^ib^kc^i| \,(i+k)\equiv1 \pmod 3\}$$ and  I'm clueless. Can someone please explain how to approach this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify what CFG is?

Comment: Context free grammar

Comment: What have you tried so far?  How have you solved similar problems like this before?

Comment: Why did you undo the edits?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial on formatting for this site, if you'd prefer to edit your own question.  You could also look at the edits that various users proposed to get ideas on how to make your expressions more readable.

Comment: Hint: since $i$ and $k$ both have three options to be equal for $\pmod 3$, they can be written as $i=\{3n, 3n+1, 3n+2\}$ and $k=\{3m, 3m+1, 3m+2\}$ ($n,m \in \Bbb N\cup\{0\}$). Hence, if $(i \equiv k) \pmod 3$, then: $(i=3n \land k=3m+1) \lor (i=3n+1 \land k=3m) \lor (i=3n+2 \land k=3m+2)$

Comment: @lulu you are right i did not read that correctly, will learn for next time!

Comment: @Yalikesifulei thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tricky part of the problem is that you have you have to manage states that keep track of what $k\bmod 3$ is so that you can only terminate when you have an appropriate number of $b$'s.  Here is a  grammar that does that (where your initial state is $S$).
$$S\to aTc\mid bV\\T\to aUc\mid V\\U\to aSc\mid b^2V\\V\to b^3V\mid\epsilon$$